# how to get a page content with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

ı want to scrape data from Instagram, Twitter. But ı cant do it with requests alone. So ı want to use a WebDriver like selenium to access the page and get the page source on the browser. How can ı get the content of the page which is opened by selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com")

html_source = driver.page_source
```

You can use the driver.page_source property